# Role Manager in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET MVC application which has few views. I have the following code for controller to restrict access for users:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Home");

            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "The user name or password provided is incorrect");

        }
        // if we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

In Web.Config:

```
        <system.web>

        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="10" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
         </authorization>

        <membership defaultProvider="LabourTimeProvider">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="LabourTimeProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LabourTime" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
          </providers>
        </membership>

      <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" >
         <providers>
           <clear />
           <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="LabourTime.CustomRoleProvider" />
         </providers>
       </roleManager>
    </system.web>

<location path="Home/Login">
    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="mydomain\mygroup" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location> 

  <location path="Home/Edit">
    <system.web>

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="mydomain\mygroup" />
        <deny users="*" />
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

In location path, if I use something like,
allow users = "my-user", it is working fine. Only the user is having access.
However, I would like a group of users in the mygroup to access the page. I don't know how to achieve this. I tried this code by doing some research but it didn't work. What to do I do in order to get access for the whole group?

When I try to login using an ID from the group, it doesn't work. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of achieving access by groups. Since you already use attributes I would suggest using the following approach:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    .....
}
```

When you wanna put logic within your code you can use a construction like this:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "ConfirmedUser")
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it is clear you are talking about a domain joined users group (part of an Intranet). In general Group Policy Objects (GPO) and Security Groups (SGs) are created within in Active Directory (AD), and domain users are member of these SGs.
In other cases DB hosted on DB Server can also be linked to same SGs, and in some cases DBs are not linked to any AD SGs, but have a different login account for an added security.
Access to these SGs are managed by IT Support Specialists of a given organization.

```
        <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
```

Having said that, upon using `<allow users="*" />` within Web.config will only allow domain users whose domain accounts are member of their appropriate Security Groups (SGs), created for their organization with in Active Directory (AD). As long as the application being developed is deployed on Application server joined to same domain, the GPOs and SGs security automatically gets synchronized to users and computer accounts for that domain. Therefore, only users member of SGs are able to access the application within an Intranet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to limit these security groups to access a web page? I mean, let's say there are three SGs (A,B, C) and I want only one SG (A) to access the web page. Is it possible?

Comment: A little PowerShell script will do the magic behind the scene upon launching your application for a Domain Logged in UserAccount: 
You can just add a bool value to confirm if logged in user account exist in the SG(A) or not:
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership 'User Account Name' | select name